# React request location permissions if status denied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, geolocation

I need some help with one issue on react. The question is how can I enable my geolocation if status denied.

Screenshot

[image: 1]

Example how to call or redirect to location settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a function to check the permission status and request permission if the status is `denied`

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(permissionStatus => {
      if (permissionStatus.state === 'denied') {
        alert('Please allow location access.');
        window.location.href = "app-settings:location";
      } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Geolocation is not supported in your browser.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error after clicking enable location. Failed to launch 'app-settings:location' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.